# Blur background in Flutter

Tags: flutter

anybody knows how to add a blur background here [image]

Here the code of this screen:

```
 return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              body: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                      Color.fromRGBO(255, 226, 89, 1),
                      Color.fromRGBO(255, 167, 81, 1),
                    ])),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100.h),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                              10.h, 10.w, 10.h, 10.w),
```

Anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

To blur the background color, we can use BackdropFilter widget

```
BackdropFilter(
   filter: ImageFilter.green(sigmaX: _sigmaX, sigmaY: _sigmaY),
   child: Container(
      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(_opacity),
   ),
),
```

Easy way to blur an image Background, We can also use BackdropFilter widget

```
Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: new DecorationImage(
        image: new ExactAssetImage('assets/image.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
      child: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1)),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [blur](https://pub.dev/packages/blur) library to make blur effects.

Check all extensions that the library provides it can be very useful to meet your requirements.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          body: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(255, 226, 89, 1),
                  Color.fromRGBO(255, 167, 81, 1),
                ])),
            child: BackdropFilter (filter: imageFilter.blur(required parameter)child: YourWidget)
```